# React native clipboard listener service for android

Tags: android, performance, react-native

I am working on an app in react native. I am searching for a code when my app is in the background or has killed. I want a service like `notifcationListnerService` which invokes the app again. want a similar service that is always running and when a user copies something it will show a push notification to the user like that you have copied something.
Here is what I have tried but these are too complex to understand because these are in java.

[Android ClipBoard Manager](https://github.com/theshid/ClipBoard-Manager)

[Android ClipBoard With Example](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-clipboard-with-examples#:%7E:text=As%20discussed%2C%20to%20paste%20the,own%20storage%20using%20getText().)

[This question from StackOverflow also does not have any answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963785/service-android-clipboard-listener)

[A solution for GitHub but too complex](https://github.com/twaddington/Android-Clipboard-Monitor)

one thing I **didn't need**  `@react-native-community/clipboard` or something like this. the thing that I need is to **show push notification on copying something for any app installed of the device**.

Answer (score 2):

So Finally searching for two days finally I have implemented what I want. I am showing a toast, not a notification(will implement it later). I am sharing my code but still, I have a problem when my application restart its service for clipboard manager the service is running as I see it in the logcat. Here is my code.

**ClipboardMonitorService.java**

```
    package com.wm;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.ClipData;
    import android.content.ClipboardManager;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.Date;
    public class ClipboardMonitorService extends Service {
        private static final String TAG = "ClipboardManager";
        private static final String FILENAME = "clipboard-history.txt";
    
        private File mHistoryFile;
        private ExecutorService mThreadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        private ClipboardManager mClipboardManager;
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
                Log.e("service is running","service is running");
            // TODO: Show an ongoing notification when this service is running.
            mHistoryFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), FILENAME);
            mClipboardManager =
                    (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            mClipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(
                    mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
    
            if (mClipboardManager != null) {
                mClipboardManager.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(
                        mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
    
        private boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    
        private ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener =
                new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPrimaryClipChanged");
                        ClipData clip = mClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
                        mThreadPool.execute(new WriteHistoryRunnable(clip.getItemAt(0).getText()));
                        Log.e("Copied Text","hahah"+clip.getItemAt(0).getText());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"My App toast",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                };
    
        private class WriteHistoryRunnable implements Runnable {
            private final Date mNow;
            private final CharSequence mTextToWrite;
    
            public WriteHistoryRunnable(CharSequence text) {
                mNow = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                mTextToWrite = text;
            }
    
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mTextToWrite)) {
                    // Don't write empty text to the file
                    return;
                }
    
                if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Writing new clip to history:");
                        Log.i(TAG, mTextToWrite.toString());
                        BufferedWriter writer =
                                new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(mHistoryFile, true));
                        writer.write(String.format("[%s]: ", mNow.toString()));
                        writer.write(mTextToWrite.toString());
                        writer.newLine();
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, String.format("Failed to open file %s for writing!",
                                mHistoryFile.getAbsoluteFile()));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "External storage is not writable!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is used for when the app is closed or the device is restarted then it will start the service again.
**BootUpRecever.java**

```
    package com.wm;
    
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Build;
    
    public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED){
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    //log("Starting the service in >=26 Mode from a BroadcastReceiver")
                    context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, ClipboardMonitorService.class));
                    return;
                }
                //log("Starting the service in < 26 Mode from a BroadcastReceiver")
                context.startService(new Intent(context, ClipboardMonitorService.class));
            }
    
        }
    }
```

to start the activity as the app start
**MainActivity.java**

```
      package com.wm;
  
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  
  import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
  public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
      return "wm";
    }
  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
      // TODO: Show the contents of the clipboard history.
      startService(new Intent(this, ClipboardMonitorService.class));
  
    }
  }
```

Here are the permissions and to start the service
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.wm">
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
        <application
          android:name=".MainApplication"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
          android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
          <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
          </activity>
          <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
            <service
                android:name=".ClipboardMonitorService"
                android:label="Clipboard Monitor"
                android:exported="false"/>
            <receiver
                android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

Comment: here is one problem that the activity is starting but not showing anything on the log.