# How to remove listener from Clipboard manager when using the method reference operator?

Tags: java, android, clipboard, method-reference

I have started using the method reference operator `::` in java.
I am basically adding a Clipboard listener to the clipboard manager like this:

```
    this.clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(this::doSomething);
```

but since this way I don't get a reference to the listener I have just added, how would I remove the listener then?

Like this?

```
    this.clipboardManager.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(this::doSomething);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with method references. You got a reference, you just decided not to store it. To solve the problem, change the code to store the reference, e.g. use `ListenerType variable = this::doSomething; this.clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(variable); …………… this.clipboardManager.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(variable);` It would be the same when creating the listener instance via `new …` or a factory method.

Comment: @Holger so it's the equivalent of this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35229183/9919250

Answer (score 0):

You're adding an anonymous class and then trying to remove a separately created anonymous class, that doesn't exist.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).